# How to store a long text in SQL Server Express and how to use it in .NET?

Tags: .net, sql-server-express, sqldatatypes

I need to store email messages in my SQL Server Express database instance. Considering this could be a very long string, I decided to use `Text` data type in the DB. However, there is no equivalent to this in .NET. Is that a good choice for this type of object to store?

I found out that `text` is going to be deprecated and developers should use `varchar(max)` instead. What `max` value would I have to set then?

What should I use in my WPF application to take that objects? By default, Visual Studio uses `string` in the code generated by Entity Data Model but is it enough?

Comment: `Varchar(max)` and `string` should be fine, as long as your strings are under 2GB (if I remember rightly).

Comment: @Bridge and if your strings are 2G you probably shouldn't use SQL Server to store them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably use String and Varchar. In `Varchar(max)`, max only species the maximum possible length, and does not cause it to be allocated for each row in the table. Same for String.

You can use the maximum reasonable (under 2gb) value you want the application to handle.

Comment: i would consider NVARCHAR(MAX) if you have customers outside the US :-)